# eliminate duplicate array values in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have an array of type `bigint`, how can I remove the duplicate values in that array?

Ex: `array[1234, 5343, 6353, 1234, 1234]`

I should get `array[1234, 5343, 6353, ...]`

I tested out the example `SELECT uniq(sort('{1,2,3,2,1}'::int[]))` in the postgres manual but it is not working.

Answer (score 148):

I faced the same. But an array in my case is created via `array_agg` function. And fortunately it allows to aggregate **DISTINCT** values, like:

```
  array_agg(DISTINCT value)
```

This works for me.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not supported for window functions.

Comment: tks guy `trim(string_agg(distinct to_char(z.dat_codigo,'0000000000'),'')) as dat_codigo,`

Comment: select array_agg(DISTINCT Array[1,2,2,3])  gives "{{1,2,2,3}}"

Comment: @user48956, that is logical, as you enter an array as value, you need to set a single column as value that is grouped by in the query

Answer (score 106):

The [`sort(int[])` and `uniq(int[])` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#INTARRAY-FUNC-TABLE) are provided by the **intarray** contrib module.

To enable its use, you must [install the module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9025515/1048572).

If you don't want to use the intarray contrib module, or if you have to remove duplicates from arrays of different type, you have two other ways.

If you have at least PostgreSQL 8.4 you could take advantage of `unnest(anyarray)` function

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST('{1,2,3,2,1}'::int[]) ORDER BY 1);
 ?column? 
----------
 {1,2,3}
(1 row)
```

Alternatively you could create your own function to do this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort_unique (ANYARRAY) RETURNS ANYARRAY
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $body$
  SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT DISTINCT $1[s.i]
    FROM generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) AS s(i)
    ORDER BY 1
  );
$body$;
```

Here is a sample invocation:

```
SELECT array_sort_unique('{1,2,3,2,1}'::int[]);
 array_sort_unique 
-------------------
 {1,2,3}
(1 row)
```

Comment: The solution of the problem ("eliminate duplicate array values") not need to *sort*. Although usually be a useful feature, it is unnecessary (CPU cost) in  this context/requirement.

Comment: Well it is actually needed, uniq only "eliminate neighbor duplicates". Take care!

Answer (score 35):

... **Where the *statandard* libraries** (?) for this kind of *array_X utility*??

Try to search... See some but no standard:

- [postgres.cz/wiki/Array_based_functions](http://postgres.cz/wiki/Array_based_functions): good reference!
- [JDBurnZ/postgresql-anyarray](https://github.com/JDBurnZ/postgresql-anyarray/blob/master/stable/anyarray_uniq.sql), good initiative but needs some collaboration to enhance.
- [wiki.postgresql.org/Snippets](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Category:Library_Snippets), frustrated initiative, but "offcial wiki", needs some collaboration to enhance.
- [MADlib](http://madlib.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/group__grp__array.html): good!  .... but it is an elephant, not an "pure SQL snippets lib".

---

### Simplest and faster `array_distinct()` snippet-lib function

Here the simplest and perhaps faster implementation for `array_unique()` or `array_distinct()`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_distinct(anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS $f$
  SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT x) FROM unnest($1) t(x);
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

---

NOTE: it works as expected with any datatype, except with array of arrays,

```
SELECT  array_distinct( array[3,3,8,2,6,6,2,3,4,1,1,6,2,2,3,99] ), 
        array_distinct( array['3','3','hello','hello','bye'] ), 
        array_distinct( array[array[3,3],array[3,3],array[3,3],array[5,6]] );
 -- "{1,2,3,4,6,8,99}",  "{3,bye,hello}",  "{3,5,6}"
```

the "side effect" is to explode all arrays in a set of elements.

PS: with JSONB arrays works fine,

```
SELECT array_distinct( array['[3,3]'::JSONB, '[3,3]'::JSONB, '[5,6]'::JSONB] );
 -- "{"[3, 3]","[5, 6]"}"
```

---

Edit: more complex but useful, a "drop nulls" parameter

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_distinct(
      anyarray, -- input array 
      boolean DEFAULT false -- flag to ignore nulls
) RETURNS anyarray AS $f$
      SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT x) 
      FROM unnest($1) t(x) 
      WHERE CASE WHEN $2 THEN x IS NOT NULL ELSE true END;
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: can you please explain what is t(x) doing in FROM unnest($1) t(x)  ...also how can i keep the order of items in which they  inserted

Comment: @abhirathore2006 this answer is a Wiki, you can write the explanations that you suggested. About "keep the order", no, it is a destructive solution, See PLpgSQL solutions in this page to preserve original array order. It is also commom the two requiriments, *sort* and *distinct* (see sucess of [main answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3995141/287948) and my comment there).

Comment: no worries, i already found the solution from somewhere else, yes that is plsql solution

Answer (score 20):

Using `DISTINCT` implicitly sorts the array. If the **relative order** of the array elements needs to be preserved while removing duplicates, the function can be designed like the following: *(should work from 9.4 onwards)*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_uniq_stable(anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS
$body$
SELECT
    array_agg(distinct_value ORDER BY first_index)
FROM 
    (SELECT
        value AS distinct_value, 
        min(index) AS first_index 
    FROM 
        unnest($1) WITH ORDINALITY AS input(value, index)
    GROUP BY
        value
    ) AS unique_input
;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Comment: best answer! see also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211501/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-any-array-and-preserve-ordering-in-postgresql

Answer (score 13):

I have assembled a set of stored procedures (functions) to combat PostgreSQL's lack of array handling coined `anyarray`. These functions are designed to work across any array data-type, not just integers as intarray does: https://www.github.com/JDBurnZ/anyarray

In your case, all you'd really need is `anyarray_uniq.sql`. Copy & paste the contents of that file into a PostgreSQL query and execute it to add the function. If you need array sorting as well, also add `anyarray_sort.sql`.

From there, you can peform a simple query as follows:

`SELECT ANYARRAY_UNIQ(ARRAY[1234,5343,6353,1234,1234])`

Returns something similar to: `ARRAY[1234, 6353, 5343]`

Or if you require sorting:

`SELECT ANYARRAY_SORT(ANYARRAY_UNIQ(ARRAY[1234,5343,6353,1234,1234]))`

Return exactly: `ARRAY[1234, 5343, 6353]`

Answer (score 10):

Here's the "inline" way:

```
SELECT 1 AS anycolumn, (
  SELECT array_agg(c1)
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c1
    FROM (
      SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1234,5343,6353,1234,1234]) AS c1
    ) AS t1
  ) AS t2
) AS the_array;
```

First we create a set from array, then we select only distinct entries, and then aggregate it back into array.

Comment: Or "more inline" ;-)    `SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT c1) FROM unnest(ARRAY[1234,5343,6353,1234,1234]) t(c1)`

Answer (score 6):

In a single query i did this:

```
SELECT (select array_agg(distinct val) from ( select unnest(:array_column) as val ) as u ) FROM :your_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

For people like me who still have to deal with postgres 8.2, this recursive function can eliminate duplicates without altering the sorting of the array

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_array_uniq(bigint[])
  RETURNS bigint[] AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    n integer;
BEGIN

    -- number of elements in the array
    n = replace(split_part(array_dims($1),':',2),']','')::int;

    IF n > 1 THEN
        -- test if the last item belongs to the rest of the array
        IF ($1)[1:n-1] @> ($1)[n:n] THEN
            -- returns the result of the same function on the rest of the array
            return my_array_uniq($1[1:n-1]);
        ELSE
            -- returns the result of the same function on the rest of the array plus the last element               
            return my_array_uniq($1[1:n-1]) || $1[n:n];
        END IF;
    ELSE
        -- if array has only one item, returns the array
        return $1;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

for exemple :

```
select my_array_uniq(array[3,3,8,2,6,6,2,3,4,1,1,6,2,2,3,99]);
```

will give

```
{3,8,2,6,4,1,99}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT if you just want this inline, you can do:

```
ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(%%someArrayHere%%) WITH ORDINALITY AS entry(value, idx) GROUP BY value ORDER BY min(idx)))
```