# Return first element in array_agg()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am writing a query to get all players for all teams. Instead of looping in the application, I decided to get the players of all teams in a single query using `array_agg()`. I have written the query as follows:

```
SELECT team_id, array_agg(team_name) AS teamname,
       array_agg(player_id||'##'||player_name) AS playerdetails
FROM team
INNER JOIN players ON team_id = player_team
GROUP BY team_id
```

This query gives me the result as below, in the result set the `teamname` is being repeated (exactly to the no. of players)

```
team_id             team_name                                                                   playerdetails
1       {Australia,Australia,Australia,Australia}                       {"5##Glenn Donald McGrath","6##Shane Warne","2##Steve Waugh","1##Adam Gilchrist"}
2       {India,India,India,India}                                       {"8##Kapil Dev","11##Saurav Ganguly","3##Rahul Dravid","9##Sachin Tendulkar"}
3       {"South Africa","South Africa","South Africa","South Africa"}   {"12##Gary Kristen","4##Shaun Pollock","7##Jacques Kallis","10##Alan Donald"}
```

Is there any way to return the result like this

```
team_id             team_name                                                                   playerdetails
1                   Australia                       {"5##Glenn Donald McGrath","6##Shane Warne","2##Steve Waugh","1##Adam Gilchrist"}
```

I have achieved it using a subquery, but want to know if its possible to write it without the subquery

```
SELECT team_id, teamname[1], playerdetails
FROM (
  SELECT team_id, array_agg(team_name) AS teamname,
         array_agg(player_id||'##'||player_name) AS playerdetails
  FROM team
  INNER JOIN players ON team_id = player_team
  GROUP BY team_id) AS tempresult
```

The [sqfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a885d) is here. And I am using Postgresql 8.4

**[EDIT]**
I was actually thinking of hack to the `GROUP BY` limitation `column "team.team_status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` when try to retrieve the a column which was not been specified in group by

```
SELECT team_id, array_agg(team_name) AS teamname,
       array_agg(player_id||'##'||player_name) AS playerdetails,
       team_status -- could be replaced by something like array_agg(team_status)[0] or customfunction(team_status)
FROM team
INNER JOIN players ON team_id = player_team
GROUP BY team_id
```

Comment: I think you can find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994556/eliminate-duplicate-array-values-in-postgres

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a sub-query?

Comment: @Patrick First the question is based on some curiosity, I have tried to do it without much success.. and I think using subquery will be less efficient when considering large and complex queries on large datasets

Comment: Note that if you didn’t have to `array_agg` on `player_id`, you could discard the `GROUP BY` clause and just use `first_value(team_name) OVER (PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY team_name)` in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It was actually a mistake from my part... the answer to my first question lies in that query itself. I just have to enclose the `(array_agg(team_name))[1]`, earlier I tried it without the brackets.

```
SELECT team_id, (array_agg(team_name))[1] AS teamname,
     array_agg(player_id||'##'||player_name) AS playerdetails
FROM team
INNER JOIN players ON team_id = player_team
GROUP BY team_id
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. This should really be the accepted answer. I can't create functions or add libraries, and I just need the first value and dont need to worry about duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to get the last element in the aggregation array, is it applicable to use ```array_agg(team_name)[-1]``` or what method should I use? I have tried with [-1] but it didn't work though.

Comment: how to add multiple columns in order by in array_agg

Comment: Why do we need to add the parenthesis in the first place? array_agg returns an array of the argument type.

Answer (score 5):

Very simply, do not aggregate the `team_name` but `GROUP BY` it:

```
SELECT team_id, team_name, array_agg(player_id||'##'||player_name) AS playerdetails
FROM team
JOIN players ON team_id = player_team
GROUP BY team_id, team_name;
```

Comment: I haven't thought of it actually, nice suggestion... but the fact is there are more tables to be joined and more select columns

Comment: Also I an expecting a generic function/implementation that can be used in other queries too..

Comment: The above answers exactly your question, you can check in your own SQLFiddle. Of course, I cannot answer things you didn't ask about. So please edit your question or post a new question. What do you mean by "generic function/implementation", for instance?

Comment: sorry about the confusion... I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT team_id, array_agg(DISTINCT team_name) AS teamname,
       array_agg(player_id||'##'||player_name) AS playerdetails
FROM team
INNER JOIN players ON team_id = player_team
GROUP BY team_id
```