# SQL group by distinct array

Tags: postgresql

I have `table1`:

```
col1 (integer)  |  col2 (varchar[]) | col3 (integer)    
----------------------------------------------------
    1           |  {A,B,C}          | 2
    1           |  {A}              | 5
    1           |  {A,B}            | 1
    2           |  {A,B}            | 2
    2           |  {A}              | 3
    2           |  {B}              | 1
```

I want summarize 'col3 ' with a GROUP BY 'col1 ' by keeping only DISTINCT values ​​from 'col3 '

Expected result below :

```
col1 (integer)  |  col2 (varchar[]) | col3 (integer)    
----------------------------------------------------
    1           |  {A,B,C}          | 8
    2           |  {A,B}            | 6
```

I tried this :

```
SELECT col1, array_to_string(array_accum(col2), ','::text),sum(col3) FROM table1 GROUP BY col1
```

but the result is not the one expected :

```
col1 (integer)  |  col2 (varchar[])       | col3 (integer)    
---------------------------------------------------------------
    1           |  {A,B,C,A,A,B}          | 8
    2           |  {A,B,A,B}              | 6
```

do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Wha is the logic behind you wanting {A,B,C}  for 1 and {A,B}  for 2?

Comment: @Matt I guess just distinct values. OP, is it possible to use array_accum(distinct col2)?

Comment: but there are 3 distinct options to pick from for each

Answer (score 0):

If the logic of which `col2` you want is by the largest (like in your expected output is `{A,B,C}` & `{A,B}`.

```
SELECT col1, (SELECT sub.col2 
              FROM table1 sub
              INNER JOIN table1 sub ON MAX(char_length(sub.col2)) = col2
              WHERE sub.col1 = col1)
       SUM(col3) 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
col1, 
array_to_string(array_accum(col2), ','::text),
sum(col3) 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY col1;
```

but array_to_string concatenates array elements using supplied delimiter and optional null string.

You have to devise a different strategy like using array_dims(anyarray) to select the array with max elements or create a new aggregation function.

For this you could be interested in this answer:

[eliminate duplicate array values in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994556/eliminate-duplicate-array-values-in-postgres)