# How can I merge an existing jsonb field when upserting a record in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Say I have a table on Postgres with a jsonb column containing `{"a": 1, "b": 2}`. Now I'd like to upsert a record with the same id and `{"b": 10, "c": 20}` as the jsonb column value.

Consequently, I'd like the jsonb field of the row to contain `{"a": 1, "b": 10, "c": 20}`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If concatenate 2 jsonb value, you achieve what you want, for example:

```
select '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'::jsonb  || '{"b": 10, "c": 20}'::jsonb
```

produces: `"{"a": 1, "b": 10, "c": 20}"`

> if both operands are objects with a common key field name, the value of the field in the result will just be the value from the right hand operand.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about upserting the new jsonb object such that the old and new one get concatenated?

Comment: If you need update existing jsonb value then you can do: `uptade table_name set col = col || '{"b": 10, "c": 20}'::jsonb where id = ?`

Comment: This will only concatenate shallowly, right? Deeply nested JSON objects are not merged recursively.

Answer (score 11):

If you want an "upsert", you can do this with `insert ... on conflict...`

```
insert into the_table (id, json_column)
values (1, '{"b": 10, "c": 20}'::jsonb)
on conflict (id) do update
   set json_column = table_name.json_column || excluded.json_column;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, my example is not about merging 2 json fields, but arrays instead:

```
insert into tag_lists (article_id, tags) values (1, '{job}')
on conflict (article_id)
do update set tags = (
  select array_agg(distinct x) from unnest(tag_lists.tags || excluded.tags) x
);
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36727422/4175647) for providing comprehensive snippets