# SQLAlchemy: how to obtain all distinct values from Array field?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following model of a blog post:

```
title = db.Column(db.String())
content = db.Column(db.String())
tags = db.Column(ARRAY(db.String))
```

Tags field can be an empty list.

Now I want to select all distinct tags from the database entries with max performance - excluding empty arrays.

So, say I have 3 records with the following values of the tags field:

- ['database', 'server', 'connection']
- []
- ['connection', 'security']

The result would be ['database', 'server', 'connection', 'security']

The actual order is not important.

Comment: This may help: [eliminate duplicate array values in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3994556/1164465)

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct()` method should still work fine with array columns.

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

unique_vals = BlogPost.query(func.unnest(BlogPost.tags)).distinct().all()
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=distinct#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.distinct

This would be identical to running a query in postgres:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(tags) FROM blog_posts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can process the results after(usually you can) and don't want to use a nested query for this sort of thing, I usually resort to doing something like;

```py
func.array_agg(func.array_to_string(BlogPost.tags, "||")).label("tag_lists")
```

and then split on the join string(`||`) after.