# golang/pq : "pq: function uniq(integer[]) does not exist"

Tags: arrays, postgresql, go, exec, insert-update

Here's my code (works fine with gin)

```
query :=`
UPDATE posts SET liked_by = uniq(array_append(liked_by, $1))
WHERE id = $2
RETURNING liked_by`

return p.DB.Exec(query, userID, post.ID)
```

The error I'm getting

```
pq: function uniq(integer[]) does not exist
```

My code works fine without `uniq()`. But the array is taking duplicate values. I wanna make sure my array only contains unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your SQL (not Go or `lib/pq`); you can replicate the problem by running the following SQL:

```sql
select uniq('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[])
```

See this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994556/eliminate-duplicate-array-values-in-postgres) for a discussion of potential solutions, one of the simplest is probably:

```sql
select array_agg(distinct x) from unnest(array_append('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[], 4)) t(x)
```

Integrating this into your code gives something like (untested!):

```golang
query :=`
UPDATE posts SET 
liked_by = (select array_agg(distinct x) from unnest(array_append(liked_by, $1)) t(x))
WHERE id = $2
RETURNING liked_by
`
```